# MySQL - How to order by any number in range

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table which manage a status data: status could be 1, 2 or 3 .

I need to order the `SELECT QUERY`, first by `2` then `3` then `1` .... or any order what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mysql's `FIELD()` function for custom ordering

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY FIELD(`status`,2,3,1)
```

or you could use `CASE`

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY 
(CASE WHEN `status` =2 THEN 1
     WHEN `status` =3 THEN 2
     WHEN `status` =1 THEN 3
     ELSE END) ASC
```

[**FIELD(str,str1,str2,str3,...)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field)